# display color of a image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to print the colors of a image.

```
import math
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("test.jpg").convert("RGBA")
color_count = 10
# im.rotate(45).show()
colors = im.getcolors(maxcolors=1000000)
max_occurence, most_present = 0, 0
for c in colors:
    if c[0] > max_occurence:
       (max_occurence,most_present) = c
print(most_present)
```

I was able to print the pixels for the picture below. Is there a way that I can extract the colors such as yellow, red, green, white, etc as the output instead of pixels?

And after getting the pixel information how do I print the colors from the pixel?

for example. `[(159, 168, 210), (23, 21, 22), (143, 107, 73), (235, 226, 199), (120, 122, 152), (211, 166, 102), (82, 62, 54), (85, 40, 37), (179, 150, 101)]` how to represent or print this as `[red, green, yellow, blue, black]` etc

[image]

Thanks,

Ankush Reddy.

Comment: Now you get the most frequent color value (i.e. white). Do you want to get specific pixel? Like im.getpixel((im.width/2, im.height/2)) ?

Comment: above code gives me the most frequent color value how to get the value of the color from the pixel value?
for example. [(159, 168, 210), (23, 21, 22), (143, 107, 73), (235, 226, 199), (120, 122, 152), (211, 166, 102), (82, 62, 54), (85, 40, 37), (179, 150, 101)]
how to represent or print this as [red,green,yellow,blue,black etc..]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from collections to count all your colors:

```
from collections import Counter
import random

#  c = Counter(im.getcolors()) 
#  print(c.most_common()) 

def t() :  # using a 3 tuple instead of image data, you plug your image in 
    return ( random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)) 

pixel = [t() for _ in range(2000)]

d = Counter(pixel)          # you stuff your colors-list in here
for i in d.most_common(10): # get the 10 most often occuring ones
    print(*i)
```

But this will only detect "exact" duplicate pixels.

Output:

```
(5, 1, 5) 6
(6, 5, 7) 6
(8, 4, 7) 6
(3, 5, 4) 6
(4, 5, 2) 6
(0, 7, 1) 5
(7, 8, 8) 5
(1, 7, 1) 5
(0, 7, 10) 5
(10, 7, 0) 5
```

For the human eye the difference between `(10,7,10)` and `(11,9,10)` are neglectiable - it is *"the same"* color. To detect all "white" ones you would need to have some kind of "grouping" function that tells you if this pixel is about the same as the others surrounding it - welcome to the world of computer vision.

There is no simple mapping for (r,b,g) = white, (r,b,g) = yellow I know of - you would have to find ranges of (r,g,b)'s yourself.

RGB id a rather unsuited colorspace for this kind of operation, HSV (Hue Saturation Value) is probably better suited: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV  - hues that are close together are "similar" colors.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to give a name to a given RGB triplet would be to use a list such as this one: https://web.njit.edu/~kevin/rgb.txt.html

You could iterate over the list (it's not that long) and find the item that is closest to your RGB triplet.

What metric you use here is probably not very important, but to refine you could consider distances along the intensity axis less important (e.g. convert RGB to HSV, and divide V by two before you compute the distance, such that the distance along V is of less importance.

The best option, but also most computationally expensive, would be to use Lab color space, which is closer to being perceptually uniform -- the Euclidean distance there is more or less meaningful.